# Visual C++ float array value changing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I am new to visual c++ and wrote the following c++ code. I was just doing some floating point multiplication nothing more :). But I have a problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define PI 3.14F
#define totalRound 10.00F

void MultiplyPIArrayStored()
{
    printf("\n\nAnalysis\n");

    float* defArr = new float[(int)totalRound];
    float inc=0.00F;
    for(float i=1.00F;i<=totalRound;i++)
    {
        defArr[(int)i]=i*PI;
        //printf("Calculation: #define => %f * %f = %f\n",i,PI,i*PI);
    }

    float lPI=3.14F;
    for(float i=1.00F;i<=totalRound;i++)
    {
        //printf("Calculation: local variable => %f * %f = %f\n",i,lPI,i*lPI);
        printf("#define =>%f; local variable=>%f\n",defArr[(int)i],i*lPI);
        if(defArr[(int)i]==i*lPI)
            inc++;
    }

    printf("\nequal rate %f percentage",(inc/totalRound)*100);
    printf("\ndifference rate %f percentage",((totalRound-inc)/totalRound)*100);
}

void MultiplyPI()
{
    printf("\n\nAnalysis\n\n");

    float lPI=3.14F;
    float inc=0.00F;

    for(float i=1.00F;i<=totalRound;i++)
    {
        printf("\nCalculation: #define => %f * %f = %f\n",i,PI,i*PI);
        printf("Calculation: local variable => %f * %f = %f\n",i,lPI,i*lPI);
        printf("#define => %f ; local variable => %f\n",i*PI,i*lPI);
        if(i*PI==i*lPI)
            inc++;
    }

    printf("\nEqual rate %f percentage",(inc/totalRound)*100);
    printf("\nDifference rate %f percentage",((totalRound-inc)/totalRound)*100);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MultiplyPI();
    getchar();

    MultiplyPIArrayStored();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

It is giving the following output.

```
Analysis


Calculation: #define => 1.000000 * 3.140000 = 3.140000
Calculation: local variable => 1.000000 * 3.140000 = 3.140000
#define => 3.140000 ; local variable => 3.140000

Calculation: #define => 2.000000 * 3.140000 = 6.280000
Calculation: local variable => 2.000000 * 3.140000 = 6.280000
#define => 6.280000 ; local variable => 6.280000

Calculation: #define => 3.000000 * 3.140000 = 9.420000
Calculation: local variable => 3.000000 * 3.140000 = 9.420000
#define => 9.420000 ; local variable => 9.420000

Calculation: #define => 4.000000 * 3.140000 = 12.560000
Calculation: local variable => 4.000000 * 3.140000 = 12.560000
#define => 12.560000 ; local variable => 12.560000

Calculation: #define => 5.000000 * 3.140000 = 15.700001
Calculation: local variable => 5.000000 * 3.140000 = 15.700001
#define => 15.700001 ; local variable => 15.700001

Calculation: #define => 6.000000 * 3.140000 = 18.840001
Calculation: local variable => 6.000000 * 3.140000 = 18.840001
#define => 18.840001 ; local variable => 18.840001

Calculation: #define => 7.000000 * 3.140000 = 21.980001
Calculation: local variable => 7.000000 * 3.140000 = 21.980001
#define => 21.980001 ; local variable => 21.980001

Calculation: #define => 8.000000 * 3.140000 = 25.120001
Calculation: local variable => 8.000000 * 3.140000 = 25.120001
#define => 25.120001 ; local variable => 25.120001

Calculation: #define => 9.000000 * 3.140000 = 28.260001
Calculation: local variable => 9.000000 * 3.140000 = 28.260001
#define => 28.260001 ; local variable => 28.260001

Calculation: #define => 10.000000 * 3.140000 = 31.400001
Calculation: local variable => 10.000000 * 3.140000 = 31.400001
#define => 31.400001 ; local variable => 31.400001

Equal rate 100.000000 percentage
Difference rate 0.000000 percentage


Analysis
#define =>3.140000; local variable=>3.140000
#define =>6.280000; local variable=>6.280000
#define =>9.420000; local variable=>9.420000
#define =>12.560000; local variable=>12.560000
#define =>15.700001; local variable=>15.700001
#define =>18.840000; local variable=>18.840001
#define =>21.980001; local variable=>21.980001
#define =>25.120001; local variable=>25.120001
#define =>28.260000; local variable=>28.260001
#define =>31.400002; local variable=>31.400001

equal rate 40.000000 percentage
difference rate 60.000000 percentage
```

**Question:** I am using a float array in the function'`MultiplyPIArrayStored();`'. If you look at the output the value stored in array is changed (Please check the last part of the output.). Is there any problem in the array declaration? Why the array value is changing?

Comment: Have you read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Comment: Canonical response to this and the myriad other questions about floating point resolution/accuracy: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: no I am new to this stuff. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is changing because that is the nature of floating point math. If you require exact values, don't use floating point math. When floating point numbers are loaded and stored, they may be subject to precision extension or precision reduction. This can cause the ending digits to change.

If you ask two people to write "1/3" as a decimal number, they may write different things. If you ask someone to write "1/3" in six digits and double it and then ask someone else to write 2/3" in six digits, you may get ".333333" doubling to ".666666" but the person writing 2/3 might write ".6666667". If you subtract 1/3 twice from 2/3. you may get .000001 left over. That's the nature of approximate representations. Don't use them if this is not the behavior you want/need.

Comment: ok thanks for the comment. Is this the case for double also? I need to get the accurate values including decimal place during calculation for some scientific purpose(for eg. calculating some frequency from device). What is the best way to do it? I mean is there any other data types or I need to use any other languages?

Comment: Yes, this is true for double also. These results are accurate to the specified number of digits (8 for single precision, 16 for double, more or less). How accurate do you need exactly? What range do you need? (Consider arbitrary precision floating point or fixed point. But you need to thoroughly understand your requirements first.)

Comment: Ok. Accuracy I can't tell. I need to get the exact values from devices but that could vary. Anyway thanks for your valuable comments:).

Comment: "Exact values" doesn't make sense. If you take 1.0 and divide by 3.0, what is the "exact value" that would be the answer you want? (If you have constraints such that exact values are in fact possible, then you have to make those part of your requirements. For example, "exact values for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division when answers are expressible with 9 or fewer decimal digits" or whatever. You need to figure out your requirements.)